# Should I learn some graph theory in order to better understand commutative diagrams (and possibly category theory)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, category-theory

I was reading Lang's *Algebra*, and on page 17 he displays the following diagram:

> [image].

I verified that the two square commute, but then I asked myself, is that really enough to prove that the entire diagram commutes? In other words, does commutativity of the squares imply the equivalence of any two paths from A to B (metaphorically)? I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823700/how-to-verify-commutativity-of-a-diagram) question and found Rob Arthan's final comment interesting, because in my case it seemed to show that, for example, $H \to G \to G/H \to G/H = H \to H/K \to G/K \to G/H$.

As I thought about this, graph theory came to mind. I know almost nothing about graph theory, but I'm wondering, would some knowledge of graph theory be worthwhile to help me better understand commutative diagrams (and possibly category theory)? Would learning some graph theory help me avoid wasting time doing redundant checks of diagrams?

I should add that on page x, Lang says "Most of our diagrams are
composed of triangles or squares as above, and to verify that a diagram consisting of triangles or squares is commutative, it suffices to verify that each triangle and square in it is commutative." Wikipedia says something similar [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram#Verifying_commutativity). However, in his *Companion to Lang's Algebra*, George Bergman says that's not necessarily true.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Randall wants to see the counterexample I mentioned in the comments below this post, so I will post screenshots of the excerpt from Lang and then from Bergman.

Lang:

> [image]
> [image]

Bergman:

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Graph theory isn't really helpful or needed here.  Yes, commutative squares "patch together" to give bigger commutative "graphs".  It's easy to prove case-by-case.  Prove that two squares patch together to give a bigger rectangle as a first step. It's trivial.

Comment: Not to say your question isn't deep.  Mac Lane spends pages upon pages worrying about things like this.  In practice, you simply check what you need when you need it.

Comment: @Randall In your first comment, are you referring to the statement that any path in a rectangle made of two commutative squares can be modified into any other path by going around squares different ways (and therefore not changing anything because of the commutativity of those squares)?

Comment: Maybe, but there's not that many ways to go around a square.

Comment: I guess for a rectangle made of two commutative squares, (like above), the only paths to check are the ones from $H$ in the top left to $G/H$ in the bottom right, and there are only three ways that I see to do this. You can go down and along the bottom, or right and then down, or you can go right, down right.

Comment: All three paths are equivalent because any one of the three paths can be made into either of the other two by changing how you go around a square (or two squares), and commutativity of the squares ensures that these adjustments change nothing.

Comment: Maybe I should just accept that a diagram comprised of polygons is *probably* commutative if all its constituent polygons are commutative, but keep in mind that this isn't always true.

Comment: Not probably, but definitely.

Comment: @Randall But I mentioned in my question that George Bergman says that's not true. On pages 168--169 of his *Companion*, he gives as an exercise a commutative square (on page ix of Lang) and instructs the reader to draw a fifth object in the center, so that the square is now comprised of four triangles. He says that commutativity of the four triangles does not guarantee commutativity of the square. (I have not done the exercise.)

Comment: I would have to see the exercise, but that never really occurs in practice.

Comment: And this quote " a diagram is commutative if every polygonal subdiagram is commutative" is what I was saying originally.

Comment: Also, I can visualize Bergman's point, but it depends on how the arrows are oriented in the triangles.  This could be a good question for the site.

Comment: @Randall I'm happy to take you at your word that whatever point Bergman is making is not a significant objection to Lang's statement (or your position, from what I understand). Assuming I haven't misunderstood what you've been saying.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the Bergman exercise explicitly written down.

Comment: @Randall See the edit to my question.

Comment: Just to re-emphasize, graph theory is of no relevance at all here because there's no inherent notion of two paths being equal in a graph that doesn't have a category structure.

Answer (score 12):

As the only thing you're doing when checking commutativity is tracing paths, familiarity with graph theory will not be much use here, unless you just wanted to practise intuiting about tracing paths out.
Ultimately, when in doubt, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the pieces you've shown to be commutative do indeed imply commutativity of the entire diagram.

If you're still in doubt, you can always write these all down as equations (since commutative diagrams are ultimately just a visual presentation of a system of equalities of morphisms).
For example, in the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>a>> B @>b>> C \\
@VuVV @VvVV @VVwV \\
X @>>p> Y @>>q> Z
\end{CD}
showing that the two squares commute amounts to showing that (1) $va=pu$ and (2) $wb=qv$.
From this, you can deduce commutativity of the perimeter just by equations:
\begin{align*}
wba \stackrel{(2)}= qva \stackrel{(1)}= qpu
\end{align*}
You can then trace these intermediates to see what they mean in the original commutative diagram, to also see how commutativity of the squares play a role.

In general, we're not usually concerned with commutativity of *everything in sight* but rather commutativity in the sense that the diagram has an "obvious" source and an "obvious" target, and we want all possible paths from the source to the target to commute.
For example, consider the pullback square

[image: pullback square]

This sort of thing is also why commutativity is usually checked by showing all polygonal pieces commute: all of the polygonal pieces, and the entire diagram, have some consistent "direction" to them. In my original example, this direction is "from $A$ to $Z$", and in the squares, the sub-directions ("$A$ to $Y$" and "$B$ to $Z$" respectively) are consistent with this.
In general, if you have a (planar) commutative diagram where all the sub-polygons have an obvious direction that is consistent with the direction of the overall diagram, then commutativity of the overall diagram will follow from commutativity of the individual pieces (this is also true for the pullback diagram shape I provided: if the triangles and the square commute, then definitely the entire diagram will commute).

As for the counterexample you mentioned in the comments (create a square and add a point in the middle), the reason for the failure is that if all the arrows to the new object point inwards, then there's no "consistent direction" among the triangles, so commutativity of the four triangles may not imply commutativity of the perimeter of the square.

Just for the record, an explicit counterexample to this is the following: take a non-commutative square of sets
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> D
\end{CD}
and then make the fifth middle object be the one-element set. Connect every set to this with the unique map into the one-element set, then the triangles will automatically all commute, but the perimeter will fail to.
**Edit:** since this is mentioned in your edit, you could also replace the one-element set with the empty set and reverse the direction of all four arrows, then again the triangles will all commute.

Comment: Better said than me.